# pass a callback function to react-admin resource

Tags: reactjs, callback, react-admin

```
class Home extends React.Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showModal : false
        }
    }
    ...

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
            ...

                <Admin theme={myTheme} dataProvider={myDataProvider} layout={MyLayout}>
                    <Resource title="Users" name="users" list={UserList}/>
                </Admin>
            ...
```

I want to pass a callback function with UserList, cause UserList has a button, when I'll press that, I want to show some modal.

In my UserList :

```
export const UserList = (props) => (
    <List {...props}
          pagination={<PostPagination/>}
          actions={<NoneActions/>}
    >
```

**How can I pass a function to Resource-Component?** *I want to receive a callback function inside the props of UserList.*

Comment: Can you please explain the usecase?

Comment: passing some extra is really helpful like, if a field is equal to something then do something based on props passed, and if the field is something make some callback to do some additional operations..

Comment: You're still explaining a technical solution you'd like, not the functional usecase